# Sending a private Teams message within c#

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Is it be possible to sent private team message within c# with using visual studio 2013. I'm currently building the custom application with following the steps of sent message in a chat https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp. Now I'm facing issue in create an auth provider by reffering https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS .Mostly all Microsoft graph authentication provider needs add the Azure.Identity package. Azure.Identity requires .NETStandard 2.0 which was not supporting by visual studio 2013 any solution to create an auth provider without using Azure Identity Package

Comment: Hello @Johnny - Is there any specific reason to use Visual Studio 2013 ? If not, you can try to upgrade it to VS2019 or VS2022 and try your code ? Link: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/

Comment: You can use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http to send a new message to a chat. Or you can also use deeplinks to create private chats between users - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links?tabs=teamsjs-v2#navigate-to-a-chat